# How can I keep track of nginx restarts and reloads?

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy

I have an nginx reverse-proxy on a ubuntu server in AWS. How can I see when it's configurations were reloaded, either via CLI or otherwise, and when it was restarted altogether?

If it doesn't record these events on its own, how can I log them indirectly through a script of some kind?

Comment: Is your `nginx` server running as a `systemd` service?

Comment: If your nginx has a lua module enabled then you could use `init_by_lua_block` to write to log file on config reload/restart.

Comment: @Uberhumus yes it is

Comment: @AlexeyTen ok I will research this approach further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some auditd rules

```
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/nginx -k nginx_exec
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S kill -F a0=1 -F a1=9 -k nginx_restart
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S kill -F a0=1 -F a1=1 -k nginx_reload
```

You can then check with

```
ausearch -k nginx_exec
ausearch -k nginx_restart
ausearch -k nginx_reload
```